# unexpected output with pandas merge_asof (missing rows)

Tags: python, pandas, merge, spyder

I want to merge the two data frames based on the nearest timestamp, the case is as following

```
Time stamp  Value1  Time Stamp 2    Value 2
13:30   A   13:32   40
13:30   B       
13:30   C       
13:30   D       
13:30   E       
13:30   F
```

the above is the dataframe where value 1 is (A,B,C,D,E) and value 2 is 40 with a different time stamp, i want to merge the 40 with (A,B,C,D,E) so i get the following result:

```
13:30   A   40
13:30   B   40
13:30   C   40
13:30   D   40
13:30   E   40
13:30   F   40
```

I have already used merge_asof method and i got this result

```
13:30   F   40
```

I used the following code:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df_downtime,df_centerline,on='Time',direction='nearest',by='Desc Variable',allow_exact_matches=False)
```

Comment: the table looks stupid

Comment: You don't define all the inputs, your example should be reproducible, minimal, and self-sufficent

Comment: @mozway can you explain more

Comment: you can read the help on how to format your question, also check my corrections

Comment: @mozway i think the table is correct, i was missconfused, what corrections?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  If your question include a pandas dataframe, please provide a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: What are the values of the other rows in the dataframe? Is is NaN? What is the "nearest time stamp"? Can you make a more useful example?

Comment: @alec_djinn the other rows of value 2 will be the same but different time stamp, for example 
Time stamp Value1 Time Stamp 2 Value 2
13:30 A 13:32 40
13:30 B 14:15 50
13:30 C  
13:30 D  
13:30 E  
13:30 F
  
14:00 A  
14:00 B  
14:00 C  
14:00 D  
14:00 E  
14:00 F

desired result
13:30 A 40
13:30 B 40
13:30 C 40
13:30 D 40
13:30 E 40
13:30 F 40
14:00 A 50
14:00 B 50
14:00 C 50
14:00 D 50
14:00 E 50
14:00 F 50

Comment: @alamazahreh Then please, post a proper example, do not skip values or columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your example is ambiguous and not reproducible, if you obtained the result you provided it is likely that you have used an incorrect order of the parameters.

[`merges_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) is a **left** merge, so you should probably use:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df_centerline, df_downtime,
                   on='Time', direction='nearest',
                   by='Desc Variable', allow_exact_matches=False)
```